# Bars not displaying for low values in Bar chart

Tags: angular, d3.js

Bar chart not displaying bars for low values in chart.

Bar chart not displaying bars for low values in chart. For example, have values like 16, 100000002, 21030404020, 3020291020. Then bars are displaying for all except value 16.

```
var data = [
{"code": "China", "value": 4}, 
{"code": "UK", "value": 17016}, 
{"code": "Japan", "value": 256536955}, 
{"code": "USA", "value": 29740072}
]

var margin = { top: 4, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 30 };
    const width = 1200 - (margin.left + 30) - margin.right;
    const height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    let x: any;
 if(id === 'currrencySvg') {
    x =d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.81);
 } else {
    x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.91);
 }
   var leastValue = parseFloat(4);
   var highestVal = parseFloat(256536955);
    let labels = [];
    x.domain(res.map(function (d) { 
      labels.push(d['code']);
      return d['code']; 
    }));
    const rangeVal = this.getStepVal(leastValue, highestVal, 10);
    const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([rangeVal['low'], rangeVal['high']]).range([height, 0]);
    const chart = d3.select('#barchart')
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (margin.left + 50) + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    let xAxis: any;
    xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0);
    const self = this;
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(function(d) { 
      return self.valueToMillions(d);
    }).tickSizeOuter(0);
    chart.append('g').call(yAxis);
    chart.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')').call(xAxis);

    let tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

    chart.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0 - (margin.left + 43))
      .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .attr("class", "chartYaxisText")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text('Spend');
    // bar chart
    let bar = chart.selectAll("rect")
      .data(res)
      .enter().append("g");

    bar.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "barGraph")
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return x(labels[i]);
      })
      .attr("y", function (d, i) {
        return y(d['value']);
      })
      .attr("height", function (d, i) { return height - y(d['value']); });
```

Bar should plot for china.

Comment: It will plot , just that you cant see the bars compared to other values. this is normal.

Comment: Yes, That is correct but if i want to see that bar what we need to do here